# How to perform MCMC posterior sampling of $X+Y$ random variable?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, data-imputation, data-augmentation

Let $X$ follow normal distribution with mean $\mu_X=10$ and variance $V_X=20$. Let $Y$ follow truncated normal distribution with mean $\mu_Y=-10,V_Y=8$, where $Y\leq 0$ by truncation.

Let $Z=X+Y$. Denote $z_1,\dots, z_N$ be $N$ realizations of $Z$. Now I want to recover $\mu_X,V_X,\mu_Y,V_Y$. Suppose I put appropriate priors on $\mu_X,V_X,\mu_Y,V_Y$.

$Q:$ How do I conduct MCMC posterior sampling for $\mu_X,\mu_Y,V_X,V_Y$? Looking at the likelihood of $Z$, I do not find an easy way to implement Gibbs sampling. Is it possible to conduct MCMC by data augmentation?

Comment: Re "The pdf of Z is not simply a sum of two distributions:" Huh? It is explicitly *defined* as a sum of two random variables.  Moreover, if by "distribution" you mean a density function, then the sum of two density functions is *never* a density function (it integrates to $2$ rather than $1,$ as it must).  These inconsistencies between your mathematical expressions and your language will make readers wonder what your question really is.

Comment: @whuber My bad for phrasing the question incorrectly. The CDF is the convolution of two densities. Thus PDF is not straight sum of two densities by some appropriate weighting. That is my point.

Comment: Are you therefore trying to ask why the sum of random variables is not a mixture of the two?  What really is your underlying objective here -- to estimate the parameters $\mu_X$ *etc.* or something else?

Comment: @whuber I want to conduct MCMC sampling scheme to sample $\mu_X,V_X,\mu_Y,V_Y$'s posterior. I do not know whether data augmentation is going to work here or is even possible.

Comment: Since your question is about sampling the posterior, *it's not about data augmentation and it's not about convolutions or PDFs.*  You will be better served, then, by editing your post to focus on what you need to know.